# How can I automate filetype detection when using sudoedit?

Tags: filetype, unix, sudo

`sudoedit`/`sudo -e` is often used for safely editing files as root. The way it works:

- `sudoedit` copies the named files to temporary files
- Then it opens the temporary files using the commands specified by the `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` variables,
- That command is run as the user who ran `sudo`, instead of `root` (or whoever the target user is).

So, the editor runs under the user's environment, and not as root. And that is excellent if your user configuration has better completion and syntax highlighting than the system Vim.

#### The problem

Since the files are copied to temporary files, the filename and location, which are often identifying characteristics for `filetype` detection, are lost. So, where `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` would load syntax highlighting suitable for Apache2 configuration files (`set ft` returns `filetype=apache`), `/var/tmp/apache2XXcLFdTD.conf` has `filetype=conf`.

So, how do I get Vim called by `sudoedit` to correctly detect the filetype as it normally would, as if I'd opened the file directly in Vim?

Bonus: It would be great to have any other settings that might have applied (like `autocmd`s) work too.

#### Useful information

The `sudo` command originally ran is available in the environment variable `SUDO_COMMAND`. For example, with `sudoedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`<sup>1</sup>:

```
:echo $SUDO_COMMAND
sudoedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

It could be split to get the filenames - however, it's not easy to safely do this if filenames contain spaces.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Surprisingly, `SUDO_COMMDAND` contains the same string even if I'd run `sudo -e /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.</sup>

Another source could be to use `/proc/<PID>/cmdline`, which contains the commandline in a NUL-delimited format. The PID here would be Vim's parent ID, so something like:

```
:let ppid = system('ps -o ppid:1= -p ' . getpid())
:let cmdline = readfile('/proc/' . ppid . '/cmdline')
```

(Of course, `readfile` splits on `LF` and filenames *can* contain that, but for now, I'm not running around editing files with newlines in the name.)

A third way could be to use a wrapper script in `EDITOR`/`VISUAL`/`SUDO_EDITOR`. The original filenames are not directly available:

```
$ EDITOR='printf %s\n' sudo -e /etc/apache2/apache2.conf -p
/var/tmp/apache2XXyMSNHX.conf
/var/tmp/-p.XXCW2H47
sudo: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf unchanged
sudo: -p unchanged
```

However, we could use `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` more easily in a shell script, perhaps.

---

Even if I manage to get the filenames somehow, how do I get Vim to use them to apply the correct `filetype` settings?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker `sudo` isn't a Linux tool, but `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` is pretty Linux-specific, I think. At any rate, I don't care about Unices in general - only Linux. (And, at the moment, `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` offers the safest way of getting filenames.)

Comment: `/proc` pre-dates Linux by about a decade. Many systems have a procfs (although they're all slightly incompatible, but it's mostly the same; other systems don't have `/proc/cpuinfo` and that sort of nonsense, but that's not needed here). And I don't see why you need it anyway, as you can just use `$SUDO_COMMAND` (I don't understand why you think it's "not easy to safely do this if filenames contain spaces")?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker `/proc` is old, `/proc/.../cmdline` *isn't*, and even on systems that do have it, there's no guarantee they will be NUL-delimited like Linux's `/proc/.../cmdline`. Try `sudoedit 'foo.conf bar.conf' baz.conf` and get me back the correct filenames. (To get into the correct frame of mind, read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and imagine you're answering this question on [unix.se].)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker *BSDs are phasing out procfs.

Answer (score 5):

#### [tpope/vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch)

Like you've discussed, `$SUDO_COMMAND` can be used to find the original filename(s). Together with a nifty usage of [`fnameescape`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#fnameescape()) and [`doautocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#:doautocmd) it is possible to deduce the correct filetype.

This is what **[tpope/vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch)** does:

https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch/commit/4087a5463ff1d9e779dace6fddbdad10e072c1ea

If filetype detection is all you want, it should be possible to transform it to something that could be included in a vimrc file.

---

#### Sudo environment variables

Since sudo 1.8.13 however, the environment variables used by `sudo` or `sudoedit` are no longer exposed or available in vim like they used to:

https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=688

```
$ sudoedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
:if !exists("$SUDO_COMMAND") | echo "undefined" | endif
undefined
```

To restore `$SUDO_COMMAND` one can use a wrapper function with an inline environment variable instead:

**bash:** ([source](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch/issues/31))

```
function sudoedit() {
    SUDO_COMMAND="sudoedit $@" command sudoedit "$@"
}
```

**fish:** ([source](https://github.com/timss/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/fish/functions/sudoedit.fish))

```
function sudoedit
    set -lx SUDO_COMMAND "sudoedit $argv";
    command sudoedit $argv;
end
```

Comment: That bugfix is disappointing. :( If I do go the wrapper, I'd probably define a variable for each argument or something. Looks like `/proc/<PPID>/cmdline` is the best way on Linux.

Comment: @muru Aye, if you're not opting for eunuch there are possibly better ways than these wrapper functions and `$SUDO_COMMAND`. Would be interesting to see a full `cmdline` based solution as well!

Comment: That bug report didn't mention `$SUDO_COMMAND`.