# Can I apply one file's filetype to another, without actually opening the first file?

Tags: filetype

For context, see [How can I automate filetype detection when using sudoedit?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6784/205)

Say `filea` has `filetype` `foo`, which is detected based on varying factors, including the name, the full path or the contents of the file (or combinations thereof). I have a buffer containing `filea`'s contents, and I want to apply `filea`'s `filetype`, without actually opening `filea`.

Assume that I already have the path and name of the file, and the contents are in the current buffer.

How do I go about this?

---

Note that I may not be able to open the actual file. A simple example is Polkit configuration in Ubuntu systems. Files in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` are accessible only to root.

---

Thanks to Carpetsmoker's tip about `:filetype detect`, I came up with one way. Something like the following could do the trick:

```
function SetActualFiletype (actual_path)
    let l:cur_file=expand('%')
    exec 'file' fnameescape(a:actual_path)
    filetype detect
    exec 'file' fnameescape(cur_file)
endfunction
```

This way, Vim has access to everything it would normally have when opening that file.

This isn't safe from `autocmd`s which are writing the file (and other such oddities).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36986/discussion-on-question-by-muru-can-i-apply-one-files-filetype-to-another-witho).

Comment: Tim Pope's [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) advertises filetype detection based on the original filename. Didn't look how it handles it, and I don't know if it was already mentioned in your other thread.

Comment: @VanLaser no, it hasn't been mentioned yet, and I think it might be the answer to a third question as well: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/258/205